# Problems with NSString UTF8 Encoding

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I'm reading a bluetooth characteristic and saving it into a string named temp below.

```
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

For some reason, when characteristic.value is an empty string, temp gets created with the value @"", which makes sense, but its temp.length is showing up at 17.

Details about characteristic.value:

```
(lldb) po characteristic.value
(NSData *) $0 = 0x1f5d9c70 <00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000>
(lldb) po characteristic.value.length
error: property 'length' not found on object of type 'NSData *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

When I try to determine if temp is an empty string, the logic doesn't work

```
if([temp isEqualToString:@""]){
```

What's also weird is that when I breakpoint and use the terminal to print the object, I get this...

```
(lldb) po temp
(NSString *) $0 = 0x1ddcf880 [no Objective-C description available]
(lldb) po temp.length
error: property 'length' not found on object of type 'NSString *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Does anyone know what's going on with this string?

Comment: When you say "`characteristic.value` is an empty string", what do you mean? When you look at `[characteristic.value length]`, what does that report? And if that's not zero bytes, then perhaps you can `NSLog("%@", characteristic.value);`, too, so we can see the hex dump of its contents. You're latter messages make me wonder if the `NSString` initialization failed (maybe `characteristic.value` is `nil`?) Are you using ARC? If not, uninitialized variables are unreliable.

Comment: Rob, I have updated the question to include information about characterstic.value. I am using arc.  Since characteristic.value is <000...000>, could this cause the NSString initialization to fail?

Comment: Are you sure that the encoding it's UTF8? Maybe the encoding it's different and that's why you don't see the character printed.

Comment: Well, binary 0000... is not a string, so it wouldn't be a valid string. Check your initialization of `characteristic.value`. By the way, to check the `length` of the data, it's not `po characteristic.value.length` but rather `po [characteristic.value length]`.

Comment: An NSString can contain nulls. The string you give it happens to have seventeen null characters in a row. Just remove nulls from the start and end of the string to solve.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri no, it's clearly not a string at all. It's a 17 byte binary buffer with 0x00 for each byte.

Comment: @Velox, we can see from the NSLog that it's just 17 bytes. If you "trim" the nulls, you have a string of length zero. Frankly, I'm skeptical that this was ever properly initialized.

Comment: you guys are right, since 0 isn't a standard ascii character, the initialization failed.  I changed the bluetooth device firmware to report 32's (spaces) instead of 0's when the string is empty, and then I trim any white spaces upon reading it.  Thanks!